# High-frequency pulsed current source not pulsing full current as expected (Keithley 228A + MOSFET switching)

Tags: current, pulse, source

I'm trying to create a pulsed current source (square wave, 50%, 0-40 MHz, 2 A p-p). For this I'm using a Keithley 228A 0-10 A current source, and a custom board consisting only of a MOSFET plus driver.

The MOSFET and driver work fine and pulse the current as expected; that is not the issue. At, say, 10 MHz the power supply will output only ~0.085 A @ 10 VDC. At 1 kHz it's the same story, 0.5 A @ 5 VDC.

Why is this? Is it an issue with my Keithley 228A (or 4-quadrant current sources in general), or is there another issue preventing me from getting the full current? What might be a solution to the issue? Is my only solution creating my own current source?

There is no load. This setup is to aid in the design of magnetics for current sensing. Direct short of keithley through the fet switch. Load is dead short 0 Ohm.

EDIT: I tried using the idea of two mosfets in parallel, one inverted from the other (two duplicate circuits as shown below, but i rewired the driver into inverting mode on one of the two boards). Works better, but still not perfect, 1MHz i can get an amp (no more though), but at 10MHz i can only get 0.5Amps.

Edit 2: I don't know what more information is needed. to me its all here: How to take a Keithley 228A and turn it into a 2 Amp 20MHz+ pulsed current source, and/or why isn't my example schematic behaving correctly (which was partially resolved by using an inverted driver + FET in parallel).

Here's an excerpt from the schematic. Nothing really of interest here, I think.

[image: schematic without capacitors]

Comment: I'm missing the load the current source feeds, or at least where it is to be connected. I have no idea where the currents and voltages stated do apply. What is the value of VDD?

Comment: Exactly what impedance do you hope to have at Q2 drain? Also its gate resistance isn't rated but I suspect it's too large to even get ***40MHz*** into the poor thing, let alone drive a load with it.

Comment: No load. Testing magnetics for current sensing (current source + & - connect as shown). Vdd would be 5v. Yes, this specific one won't do 40mhz. This is a proof of concept before I create another, that will have to use all bga parts (not ideal but doable). Wanted to start with easy to solder parts.

Comment: When the NMOS is not ON, there is no path for the current from Keithley to flow. Shouldn't you have some low impedance between the 2 terminals?

Comment: Where's the load? This question makes no sense.

Comment: bobflux I edited the question, but I also commented this, and will do it again. There is no load. This if for testing magnetics for current sensing. @sai you are right. I assumed this would not be an issue. Is it? How might I fix it? Two mosfets, when one is on other is off and vice versa?

Comment: Is the PS in `power supply will output` the `Keithley 228A 0-10 A current source`, or something else? *Where/how* did you measure *0.085 A* / *0.5 A*?

Comment: The datasheet of the Keithley 228A mentions a load transient response time of 1 ms in the specification page, section GENERAL, so even 1 kHz FET switching is to high for proper current regulation. You need to use another current source or build one yourself.

Comment: @super7800, the actual load could be connected in parallel to the switch so that when the switch is open, the current pulse flows into the actual load. However, even if you do that I am not confident that you will get 2A pulses flowing into the load because the transient response is very slow compared to your frequency of operation as mentioned by Jens.   The other question is whether it is even ok to put the load in parallel with the NMOS because the NMOS will be shorting the load during half the period.   We need to have an electrical model of the load.

Comment: @sai the load is dead short zero ohm. Jens you are right, yeah i may need to create my own, i have other supplies but none will get me to the frequencies i need. greybeard the current supply is the keithley 228A. the fet is driven from a HP 33220A function gen, and the driver gets its +5v from a bench supply. Measured from the front panel of the keithley, and using a tek tcp202 current probe

Comment: This is an X-Y problem: you must understand first how to test current-sense magnetics at such frequencies.  Please ask that question first.  Then and only then, consider a particular solution to testing a particular current sensor.  Tip: at these frequencies, the testing fixture will likely vary, and will have to be calibrated against a given sensor under test. This is fundamentally why you are getting nonsense results from your proposed method, and getting comments going in directions other than your proposed solution.

Comment: @Tim williams I (pretty much) already know how to do that. it works using my revised circuit using inverted+non inverted mosfet in parallel, i can pulse 1 amp @ 1MHz, but higher frequencies still give issues, this is likely due to the "dead time" between the two mosfets. My previous method used a keithley 6221, but that doesnt have high enoughph frequency or current, hence why im designing this. The sensor is behaving exactly as expected, matching somewhat closely with the TCP202 probe.